# How to disable click event after drag stop in d3.js tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseclick-event

I want to disable click event after drag stop. Here is my click event :

```
function click(d) {

            if (contextDiv) {
                contextDiv.remove();
            }

            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
            update(d);
        }
```

Do you have any suggestion? I don't use Jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `d3.event.stopPropagation();`

Check out the [d3 Drag Behavior API Reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior)

Here is an example: http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/3186840

Comment: Thank you very much. I wrote this code: 
 var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", function () {d3.select("rect").on("click", function () { d3.event.stopPropagation(); });}); 
But how I can reactive my click event?

Comment: Ok I found it. I need to call update function. Thanks alot again.